# I get 400 bad request from some websites but not others with HEAD request

Tags: sockets, http, http-request, http-status-code-400

I am making a banner grabber and have finally ironed out the HEAD / HTTP/1.1 request according to the guidelines, but some websites still give me '400 Bad Request'

why is that?

Here is my request:

```
"HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: target:port\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
```

Comment: Should the `Head:` be `Host:` ? Apart from that, sites might block the `HEAD` request, i.e. there is no requirement that they must offer it. Also, the target you give in the Host header might not match a name setup on the server. Nevertheless you might get the servers banner (I.e. `Server` header I suppose) from the 400 response too, if the server sends such header at all (not required).

Comment: Thanks, @SteffenUllrich your right, I do get the header anyway but just wondered why I was getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Should the `Head:` be `Host:` ? Apart from that, sites might block the `HEAD` request, i.e. there is no requirement that they must offer it. Also, the target you give in the Host header might not match a name setup on the server. Nevertheless you might get the servers banner (I.e. `Server` header I suppose) from the 400 response too, if the server sends such header at all (not required).
                    – Steffen Ullrich